# Uncaught (in promise): Event: {\"isTrusted\":true}

Tags: angular, events, polyfills

My **Angular 5** application is getting this error in the **polyfills** bundle on some browsers. Since it does not happen on my own browser, I can't reproduce it or find out anything more about it - I'm just posting the errors that happen on the front-end -.

Any idea where it might be coming from?

Comment: Can you specify a list of browsers where this error happens ? There might be 2 explanations: CORS not set properly or you didn't uncomment the right lines in polyfills file.

Comment: Okay, it's apparently Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.2; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/), so a bot. Not entirely sure if it's worth worrying about it in that case.

Comment: the event is not supported in safari and ie, more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone interested: the error was happening because clients were blocking the Google Maps Services, but I was trying to load it anyway and not catching the rejected promise.

Now I'm just checking if Google Maps is being blocked before trying to place a map.

Comment: Hi, do you have any details on how Google Maps services could be blocked? Thanks

Comment: There are several Chrome extensions to block 3rd party scripts, don't have one particular in mind but I know that's a way of doing it